# Input variable from command line in Python

Tags: python, variables, input

What I want to do is very simple but I can't figure out a good and not too complex solution for this. Basically I want to define some global variables that will be used for example as a folder name

```
global folder = "C:\\TEMP\\" + foldername
```

And what I want is to set the foldername value as input when running the script, something like:

```
python myscript.py --folder somebeautifulfoldername
```

so when running my script, the folder will become C:\TEMP\somebeautifulfoldername

Comment: are you asking about assigning   "C:\\TEMP\\" to global variable or passing value via commandline??

Comment: Something like https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: @teoreda  : You should have actually mention this in answer, by giving and example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass arguments to Python script like following:

```
python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

And this is what you get

`Argument List: ['test.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']`

In your case:

`python myscript.py somebeautifulfoldername`

`folder = "C:\\TEMP\\" + sys.argv[1]`

Comment: How are these arguments in the "argument list" accessed in the Python script?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module for this combined with getting the command line arguments from `sys.argv`:

```
import argparse
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'My script')
    parser.add_argument('--folder', help = "Subfolder of C:\TEMP\ to manipulate")
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    folder = "C:\\TEMP\\"+args.folder
    print folder
```

Here I added just a very simple argument with some basic help string, but you can do quite a lot with this like giving a default value, allowing a list of files instead of a single file, specify the type, ... . See the manual for more details and examples.

Usage:

```
>python myscript.py --folder somebeautifulfoldername
C:\TEMP\somebeautifulfoldername

>python myscript.py --help
usage: tmp.py [-h] [--folder FOLDER]

My script

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --folder FOLDER  Subfolder of C:\TEMP\ to manipulate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

folder = "none"
if("--folder" in  sys.argv):
    folder = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("--folder") + 1]        
print folder
```

If you run it the way you want:

```
python myscript.py --folder "HELLOFOLDER"
```

It will give: HELLOFOLDER

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options to parse command line arguments into a Python script. There's the standard library's [optparse](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/optparse.html) and [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html) for instance.

A really nice 3rd party tool is [docopt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docopt/0.6.2), which allows you to write the logic described above very easily by describing the script usage directly as documentation of your script like this:

```
"""My script

Usage:
  myscript.py --folder=<folder>

Options:
  -h --help             Show this screen.
  --version             Show version.
  --folder=<folder>     Choose folder.
"""

from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='myscript 1.0')
    folder = "C:\\TEMP\\" + arguments["--folder"]
    print(folder)
```

That said, you may also want to look into [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) for generating temporary files to make the script more cross-platform. Hard-coding Windows-specific paths is rarely a good idea.